# Get Archived Chatter Group Information

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups

Can you please tell me how to know when and by whom a group was archived on chatter.

Note: The group was not inactive

please help

Answer (score 4):

The object for a Chatter Group is called `CollaborationGroup`.

Just like all objects, there are fields that track who last modified that record. So provided no other changes have been made to the group since it was archived (not re-activated), you can look to see the values for `LastModifiedDate` and `LastModifiedById`. You can also verify the archived state of the group by the `isArchived` field.

However if you've already reactivated it, that record will be lost as there is no field history for that object.

In the future, there are some things you could do to audit changes to this and reduce likelihood this happens in the future.

1. You can create a trigger on CollaborationGroup that writes specific logging information on certain changes.
2. You can create a scheduled job using one of the many data loader tools (Dataloader.io or Jitterbit offer rich functionality for free) that regularly exports collaboration group data to csv files.
3. Reduce the number of people with access to be able to modify group settings. These would be salesforce admins, moderators for communities, etc.